# Automate download of a dynamically generated file after NTLM Authentication using vbscript/java

Tags: java, excel, vbscript, ntlm, browser-automation

I am trying to automate to download a dynamically generated file on a server, so here are the steps what I have to carry out manually -

1. Login to the site using my credentials - It uses NTLM to authenticate.
2. After login fill in the details in a form, which uses post method send the details to server and generates a file on server and revert back response to server.

So first I thought of doing it using VBScript:

- Get a IE Automation object
- sendkeys to send userword/password
- Navigate to the page and download the file
- Sendkeys to switch to save button - But here i got stuck because IE prompts me for save location which I can't determine. Also I thought of opening it but I am not able to get the automation object of Excel file opened this way :(

Even `wget` can't work as I have to post some data and basis of what it will provide me the resultant Excel file.

So after searching on web I found I can do it using `MSXML2.xmlhttp` object or Java sockets and download the page using get method, but again I have to provide my credentials to open the page.

So can anybody please help me how to authenticate the user and download the file in either way.

**EDIT:** Code

--Download the page

```
objmsXML.Open "GET", url, False
objmsXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objmsXML.setRequestHeader "Referer", url
objmsXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"
objmsXML.send
```

--Fill in the details and post data

```
If objmsXML.Status = 200 Then
  'First Response received.
  'get all the response headers
  responseHeaders = objmsXML.getAllResponseHeaders()
  responseBody = objmsXML.responseText    
End If

Dim viewState As String
Dim eventTarget, eventArgument, txtProjectID, btnSubmit, grdReportPostDataValue
Dim eventValidation As String

viewState = Split(Split(responseBody, "__VIEWSTATE")(2), """")(2)
viewState = URLEncode(viewState, False)

eventTarget = ""
eventArgument = ""
txtProjectID = projectID
btnSubmit = URLEncode("Submit")
grdReportPostDataValue = ""
eventValidation = Split(Split(responseBody, "__EVENTVALIDATION")(2), """")(2)
eventValidation = URLEncode(eventValidation, False)

objmsXML.Open "POST", url, False

Dim postData
postData = "__EVENTTARGET=" & eventTarget & "&__EVENTARGUMENT=" _
  & eventArgument & "&__VIEWSTATE=" & viewState & "&txtProjectID=" _
  & txtProjectID & "&btnSubmit=" & btnSubmit & "&grdReportPostDataValue" _
  & grdReportPostDataValue & "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" & eventValidation

objmsXML.send postData
```

But the problem is it is not giving me the second page as a result of form post. I believe this might be because I am not able to track the session cookie. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the actual question is here. Are you asking how to authenticate without providing credentials?

Comment: well Ansgar, thanks for response, but my problem is both, authenticate the user and download the file.

Comment: You didn't set the request header for your second request. What is the response from the server to the second request? What does its log say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't authenticate a user without providing credentials. Manually download the file once while inspecting the session with something like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). That will reveal the headers required for the `POST` request. Then automate the request like this:

```vbs
url = "http://..."

user = "..."
pass = "..."
credentials = "username=" & user & "&password=" & pass

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "POST", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.send credentials
```

Modify `credentials` according to what Fiddler revealed. You may need to encode the values (`user` and `pass` in the example above) with something like this:

```vbs
Function Encode(ByVal str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.~-]"

  enc = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(str)
    c = Mid(str, i, 1)
    If re.Test(c) Then c = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(c)), 2)
    enc = enc & c
  Next

  Encode = enc
End Function
```

Save the `responseBody` to a file like this:

```vbs
filename = "C:\your\output.xls"

Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

If req.status = 200 Then
  stream.Open
  stream.Type = 1 'binary
  stream.Write req.responseBody
  stream.SaveToFile filename, 2
  stream.Close
End If
```

If the filename is dynamically generated you may need to read the response and/or status text and send a second request to actually retrieve the file. However, that depends on the actual server response (as revealed by Fiddler).

**Edit:** A solution I found [here](http://powersdrill.blogspot.ch/2005/12/post-with-vbscript-using-ntlm-https.html) suggests using a [`WinHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106) object:

```
Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
req.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0

req.Open "POST", url, False
req.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.Send credentials
```

I can't test this, though, because I don't have a web server using NTLM authentication at hand.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, let me try it

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I have updated the code below the --Edit section in my question, could you please help me on that.